# Show commits affecting a file that are not in a feature branch?

Tags: git, branch, git-rebase, feature-branch

Given `branch-a` and `git rebase origin/master branch-a`, sometimes you get conflicts in a file.

```
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in .../file.txt
```

Given that before the rebase there were no conflicts (by definition), then conflicts can only have occurred b/c one or more commits to `.../file.txt`.

During the conflict resolution process, I can't figure out a way to easily show "commits from origin/master that affected .../file.txt" so that I can more confidently integrate those changes.

```
---A---B---[C]---D
    \             \
     E---[F]---G   E'--[C/F']--G'
```

`ABCD` is mainline development.  `EFG` is my local branch development.  Commit `C` caused a conflict in file/commit `F` during my local rebase onto `D`.

Given a detached HEAD or "rebasing" state, when I do `git log -3 file.txt` it doesn't seem to show me what I want to see, which is *WHAT* was the diff (ie: commit `C`) which caused the conflict I'm trying to resolve now when applying commit `F`.

How can I get a list of commits which only affect a particular file and are from the range `ABCD`... not including my commits in `EFG` or the currently active `--rebase`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the output you need with:

```
git log --patch --full-history A..D -- file.txt
```

The `--patch` (or `-p`) flag is probably the main thing you're looking for: it shows the diff for each commit logged.

The `--full-history` flag prevents Git from simplifying the history by omitting commits based on the current status of the worktree. This may not be necessary depending on your specific situation.

The `A..D` limits the output to commits between commit `A` (exclusive), and commit `D` (inclusive). This is probably a more reliable way to limit the commits instead of `-3`, assuming you have the refs for `A` and `D` handy. And actually, you will always both refs handy, because `D` is the tip of your mainline branch, and you can get `A` by doing:

```
git merge-base <mainline> <local>
```

---

A concrete example:

Assume that the mainline branch is `master`, and the other branch is `feature`.

```
git rebase master feature
# conflicts occur
git log --patch --full-history $(git merge-base master feature)..master -- file.txt
```

To save time, you could also set up an alias:

```
git config --global alias.conflict-commits "! git log --patch --full-history $(git merge-base $1 $2)..$1 -- $3"
```

Then use it as:

```
git conflict-commits master feature file.txt
```

Comment: Just an FYI... eventually I'm going to wrap up your advice into a little command/scriptlet (git conflict-commits) or something, but I haven't hit a conflict again where I've been motivated to do it.

Comment: @user400575: Your comment gave me the idea to show how to use it as an alias; I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the source for the `log` command to be `origin/master`:

```
git log origin/master -3 file.txt
```